# Save downloaded file in public Downloads directory and open it with intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-download-manager

I am having trouble downloading and opening a file.

I successfully download the file in device's public external Download folder and I can open it through File Explorer, but when I want to open it with intent right after the download has finished from my app, *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException* occurs:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /file:/storage/emulated/0/Download/Colors.pdf
            at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:719)
            at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:404)
            at com.example.alla.bitchface.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:97)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1122)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

**MainActivity.java:97** is

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider",
                                    new File(filePath));
```

I tried to implement FileProvider, but I can't figure out how to make it work with public directories. Also when I do the "hack" with removing StrictMode, the file opens. Here's my code:

```java
@Override
    public void onDownloadPrepared(Request downloadRequest, String fileName) {
        downloadRequest.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                fileName);

        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        if (manager == null) return;

        long id = manager.enqueue(downloadRequest);

        BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                long receivedId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID,
                        -1);
                if (id == receivedId) {
                    Query query = new Query();
                    query.setFilterById(id);
                    Cursor cursor = manager.query(query);

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);

                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == cursor.getInt(columnIndex)) {

                            String filePath = cursor.getString(
                                    cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));

                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider",
                                    new File(filePath));

                            intent1.setData(uri);
                            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                            startActivity(intent1);

                        }
                    }
                    unregisterReceiver(this);
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
        registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, filter);
    }
```

```xml
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

```xml
<provider
       android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
       android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
       android:exported="false"
       android:grantUriPermissions="true">
       <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
           android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

Comment: What is the value of `filePath` and `uri.toString()`,?

Comment: Probably `filePath` starts with `file://`. Strip it off.

Comment: Well, it crashes there so it has no value. :? If you're talking about Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider",
                                    new File(filePath));

Comment: Yes, it starts, I'll try

Comment: You can catch the exception so it does not crash. Or not execute the following code fir a test. Just debug.

Comment: @greenapps That was the problem...Thank you!

Comment: Try adding the path to the Download directory in your provider_paths.xml something like "path=Download/"

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "file" prefix from the path:

```
filePath = filePath.replace("file:/","");
```

> Posting this as a [Community Wiki Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741) instead of it being edited into the Question.

Comment: It's woriking fine

Answer (score -1):

The `Download` folder is not listed as a path, supported by your `FileProvider`.

Try adding the following to the `provider_path.xml`: